Highchart-export-server is exporting only once
I am using highcharts-export-server node modules version 4.0.2. It is exporting the data only once, after that it is not exporting the data without any error. After restart it works but again only once.
Am I doing anything wrong? Is it a good way to always killPool after each export.
const options = {
  export: {
    type: format,
    options: chartConfiguration
  }
};
const exportSettings = this.highChartExporter.setOptions(options);
await this.highChartExporter.initExport(exportSettings);
console.log( this.deviceData );
return this.highChartExporter
  .startExport(exportSettings, async (error: any, info: any) => {
    console.log( info );
    this.highChartExporter.killPool();
    return { type: "Sucess", data: info.result, message: "Request Processed" };
  })
  .catch((error: any) => {
    this.highChartExporter.killPool();
    return { type: "Failure", data: undefined, message: error };
  });




You shouldn't have to kill the pool after each export. Please try running the initExport once and then running multiple startExport processes and killing the pool only once all of them are finished.
